# jQuery scrolling does not work with anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to scroll the page to an anchor link. I'm using following code:

```
$('a').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
        }, 400);
        return false;
    });
```

It works fine if I have a url like this:

```
<a href="#comments">Comments</a>
```

However, the problem is that the url is automatically generated by adding the # at the end of current url, so it will be:

```
<a href="http://example/sth/#comments">Comments</a>
```

In this cause, it does not work. I cannot change the markup of the URL, how can I fix the jQuery to work with such url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the `hash` property of the anchor instead of it's `href`:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 400);
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KL5uw/

Comment: cool approach, didn't know you can do that with an anchor URL, +1 :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it was great help :)

Answer (score -1):

Scrolling to Particular anchor tag, This can be be done with HTML Only

ex:

```
<a name="top"></a>  // where we have to reach
<a href="#top">last</a>     // we reach their by clicking on this we can also use an image, align in right
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/MRQmN/)